# What's a 25 core network cable

Tags: networking, cable

While looking for different types of network cable, I came across this term called 25-core cable. You can get numerous examples putting the term '25-core cable' in any search-engine. But till date haven't found a single document which explains what this 25-core cable is or 16-core or 8-core ?

By a single core does it mean a single LAN cable which connect at both ends to a single RJ-45 connectors . If I'm assuming it right it would mean having 25 connectors at each end. This would be from taking bunch of cables from a say a 'network closet' to going doing to a basement or something which if I understand is called 'backhaul networks'.

Am I right in assuming then anything apart from a single core LAN cable is for backhaul networks or is there any other scenario where such multiple 'cores' cable is used.

Update :- meant a 25 'pair' cable and NOT 'core'. I did remember reading about it though.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about network cable?  Where did you see this?  What was the exact context?  Are you sure you aren't talking about phone cabling?  IE http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Detail.aspx/CAT3-25-Pair-Bulk-Telco-Cable-PVC-1000-ft-304-8-m/ELN25TA%C4%821000

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it certainly seems like a simpler way to backhaul multiple cables across tight areas (instead of 3 RJ45, or 12 RJ11, etc).

Comment: I never heard "25 core" but definitely heard "25 pairs", "50 pairs", "100 pairs". Whatever, don't do it for network. It sucks. cross-talk is incredibly high. Seems "easier" to run 1 25 pair but damn it sucks. Then you have them all on a punch down block, all wires untwisted etc. Good for phone, not for network.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a cable for the RJ21 connector.. like this : http://cityinfrastructure.com/Voice/DSCN2121-RJ21.jpg

Comment: ah, yes 25 pair and things like that. For e.g. http://www.indiamart.com/ratandeephardwareelectricals/computer-networking-products.html

Comment: Ouch. Looks useless for regular use - the amount of work for getting that stuff into a rack / center / even office building is not worth it.