# PVC raceway/conduit for CAT5e/CAT6/CAT6A cable

Tags: networking, cable, cable-management

This is probably a bunch of stupid questions .

The scenario is of running a few (5-6) CAT cables (version undecided, depending on costs). The scenario would be something like this :-

a 3G USB modem - 3G router having single LAN port - 16-port switch - 4-5 computers each spaced 2-3 feet apart from each other.

Now as asked before (by me) a 5-6 pair cable seems to be a bad idea [What's a 25 core network cable](https://serverfault.com/questions/582918/whats-a-25-core-network-cable)

Reading from various sources on interweb, it seems that a single PVC conduit/raceway should not have more 3 CAT cables and should be 40% of the conduit space ? Is this true or not ?

Depending on which cable is chosen, the diameter of the 3 cables together would be 15~24mm which means the diameter of the conduit should be somewhere between 35mm - 50mm. Are my calculations okish or any other recommendations ?

I looked around and zoned to PVC conduit as it seems to be the only lightweight material around. Are there any other lightweight conduits that I should look into?

Also are there any ideas to keep the cables in-place otherwise they might twist or jump around one another in the conduit, maybe possible or not ?

Lastly, if the above about having only 3 cables in one conduit is true, then I need to have at least 2 conduits stacked side by side on the wall. For future upgrades, is it recommended to have another PVC conduit or two also getting done at the same time ?

Any videos and links highly appreciated.

Comment: Shirish: You've asked a bunch of questions about networking/cabing infrastructure in the last couple of days. Perhaps it's time to realise that you need more than a Q&A site and ask your manager for some education in the tools/tasks you are being asked to use/complete.

Answer (score 2):

Not much of an answer but I'd say check your local electrical code. The code should take all those concerns into account. Sorry I couldn't be more helpand good luck.

BTW, I wanted to post this as a comment but it said I don't have permission to comment on the post.